# Issue with try catch and redirect

Tags: laravel

I am using an Payment Getaway API and when it is not correct the parameters, it shows an error my code is this one:

```
$paymentData = [
    'amount' => '200',
    'description' => 'test',
    'cardHolder' => 'jon doe',
    'cardHolderId' => '11111111',
    'cardNumber' => '4111111111111111',
    'cvc' => '123',
    'expirationDate' => '12/2019',
    'IP' => '127.0.0.1',
];

try{
    $instapago = new Instapago();
    $respuesta = $instapago->directPayment($paymentData);
 } catch(\Socialgest\Instapago\Instapago\Exceptions\InstapagoException $e){
   // redirect
   session()->put('card_error', 1);
   return Redirect::to('checkout');
 } catch(\Socialgest\Instapago\Instapago\Exceptions\TimeoutException $e){
   // redirect
   session()->put('card_error', 1);
   return Redirect::to('checkout');
}
```

The thing is that If it shows an error it could be redirected to another page how you can see I am adding redirect BUT it is not working because when an error appears it displays this, for example:

```
Socialgest \ Instapago \ Exceptions \ InstapagoException
Error cardHolder: 2323
```

And it is a very ugly message, so I wonder how can I get that error and redirect to another page? because I tried but it does not work at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing one `Instapago` from `\Socialgest\Instapago\Instapago\Exceptions\InstapagoException`. Since the error has only one.

Comment: @Digvijay you are a crack man TY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment.

Try removing one `Instapago` from `\Socialgest\Instapago\Instapago\Exceptions\InstapagoException`. Since the error has only one.

**Also**, it's always a **good practise** to add a final (at the end) `catch (Exception $e) {}` just in case if other exceptions are not catched.